# access private api gateway from browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-vpc

we have a simple serverless application structure in AWS with an api gateway + lambda, we also bind a custom domain name to the api so that our customer could use our service by hitting that URL from their browser. Since the application is only used in our company internally thus we may need to move the api into a VPC. I have read bunch of articles/tutorials on how to do it, basically we will need to create a VPC and VPC endpoint and make the VPC endpoint point to the private api gateway so that the api can be invoked within the current VPC or by privatelinks from another VPC. But our mission is that we let customers to type URL in the browser and use our service, how can we achive that if we have a private api gateway? thanks in advance

Comment: How did it go? Is it still unclear why you can't do what you wish to do with private API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But our mission is that we let customers to type URL in the browser and use our service, how can we achive that if we have a private api gateway?

Well you **can't do it directly**. Private API can only be accessed through **private IP** of same or peered VPC/VPN/DX.

If you want to make it available from the internet, you either you have to make it public, or **proxy** through some public server. Probably the easiest one would be to setup second public API gateway which invokes a **lambda function**. The function would be your proxy. So you would have:

```
Internet--->public API----> Lambda in VPC ----> private API
```

This obviously adds more code to maintain, latency and cost.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. it does look like we are not able to use the private API GW the way we imagined so we'd possibly choose to use Allegiance -> ALB -> NLB -> Lambda